# AngularJS Route - templateUrl not working

Tags: angularjs

When accessing a route, the partial template is not being showed at all.

My Index HTML (Initial Layout):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#/home">Go to Home</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Home.html

```
<h>I'm home</h>
```

My Script.js

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/home", { templateUrl: "Templates/Home.html" })
});
```

Solution Files:

[image]

Obs: This works:

```
$routeProvider.when("/home", { template: "<h>I'm home</h>" })
```

Comment: If you put it in a JSFiddle/Codepen, do you still have the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the console (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and you'll see following error:

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

I bet you are opening `index.html` using Google Chrome without running the webserver. To fix the problem you need to run code from a webserver or just use [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) instead.

In [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OlAun04Htm1eUZCCOmL5?p=preview) it works fine.